# How can I solve this bug with the setUser () method of the User Address Entity

Tags: php, symfony

Currently I am at the address of the user. I want to retrieve the logged in user to assign the new address to this user.

For this I use the getUser () method.

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

And in my view in twig when I dump the variable returned I find that it is the correct user retrieved.

```
Utilisateurs {#320 ▼
  #id: 31
  -commandes: PersistentCollection {#345 ▶}
  -adresses: PersistentCollection {#374 ▶}
  #username: "Hasmiou"
  #usernameCanonical: "hasmiou"
  #email: "diallo@xxx.com"
  #emailCanonical: "diallo@xxx.com"
  #enabled: true
  #salt: "tkkwpuzzykg4sksc8coo8048g448ooo"
  #password: "$2y$13$tkkwpuzzykg4sksc8coo8uBC0haUd5f1UQqhbt5E59xN12/jFQb2S"
  #plainPassword: null
  #lastLogin: DateTime {#318 ▶}
  #confirmationToken: null
  #passwordRequestedAt: null
  #groups: null
  #locked: false
  #expired: false
  #expiresAt: null
  #roles: []
  #credentialsExpired: false
  #credentialsExpireAt: null
}
```

Now when I continue in development, I use the setUser method of the UserAddress () entity I'm returned an error message that is:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\UtilisateurAdresse::setUtilisateur() must be an instance of Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Utilisateurs, instance of Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs given, called in C:\wamp64\www\Saresso\src\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Controller\PanierController.php on line 119 and defined
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

I noticed this error even when I used the DataFixture bundle, I was unable to pre-register users in the UserAddress entity.

Here is the code of the entity UserAddress:

```
<?php

namespace Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * UtilisateurAdresse
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateur_adresse")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Saresso\SaressoBundle\Repository\UtilisateurAdresseRepository")
 */
class UtilisateurAdresse
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Communes", inversedBy="adresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $commune;

     /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs", inversedBy="adresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false) 
     */
   private $utilisateur;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titreAdresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $titreAdresse;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="complement", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $complement;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latAdresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $latAdresse;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lonAdresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lonAdresse;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephoneAdresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephoneAdresse;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titreAdresse
     *
     * @param string $titreAdresse
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setTitreAdresse($titreAdresse)
    {
        $this->titreAdresse = $titreAdresse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titreAdresse
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitreAdresse()
    {
        return $this->titreAdresse;
    }

    /**
     * Set adresse
     *
     * @param string $adresse
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setAdresse($adresse)
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adresse
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdresse()
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    /**
     * Set complement
     *
     * @param string $complement
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setComplement($complement)
    {
        $this->complement = $complement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get complement
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getComplement()
    {
        return $this->complement;
    }

    /**
     * Set latAdresse
     *
     * @param string $latAdresse
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setLatAdresse($latAdresse)
    {
        $this->latAdresse = $latAdresse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get latAdresse
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLatAdresse()
    {
        return $this->latAdresse;
    }

    /**
     * Set lonAdresse
     *
     * @param string $lonAdresse
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setLonAdresse($lonAdresse)
    {
        $this->lonAdresse = $lonAdresse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lonAdresse
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLonAdresse()
    {
        return $this->lonAdresse;
    }

    /**
     * Set commune
     *
     * @param \Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Communes $commune
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setCommune(\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Communes $commune)
    {
        $this->commune = $commune;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commune
     *
     * @return \Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Communes 
     */
    public function getCommune()
    {
        return $this->commune;
    }

    /**
     * Set utilisateur
     *
     * @param \Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Utilisateurs $utilisateur
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setUtilisateur(\Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Utilisateurs $utilisateur)
    {
        $this->utilisateur = $utilisateur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get utilisateur
     *
     * @return \Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Utilisateurs 
     */
    public function getUtilisateur()
    {
        return $this->utilisateur;
    }

    /**
     * Set telephoneAdresse
     *
     * @param string $telephoneAdresse
     * @return UtilisateurAdresse
     */
    public function setTelephoneAdresse($telephoneAdresse)
    {
        $this->telephoneAdresse = $telephoneAdresse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telephoneAdresse
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTelephoneAdresse()
    {
        return $this->telephoneAdresse;
    }
}
```

**Entity Utilisateur**

```
<?php
// src/Utilisateurs/UtilisateurBundle/Entity/Utilisateur.php

namespace Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class Utilisateurs extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
        $this-> commandes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this-> adresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Commandes", mappedBy="utilisateur", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true) 
     */
   private $commandes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\UtilisateurAdresse", mappedBy="utilisateur", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true) 
     */
   private $adresses;

    /**
     * Add commandes
     *
     * @param \Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     * @return Utilisateurs
     */
    public function addCommande(\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes[] = $commandes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove commandes
     *
     * @param \Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     */
    public function removeCommande(\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes->removeElement($commandes);
    }

    /**
     * Get commandes
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCommandes()
    {
        return $this->commandes;
    }

    /**
     * Add adresses
     *
     * @param \Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Adresses $adresses
     * @return Utilisateurs
     */
    public function addAdress(\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Adresses $adresses)
    {
        $this->adresses[] = $adresses;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove adresses
     *
     * @param \Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Adresses $adresses
     */
    public function removeAdress(\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Adresses $adresses)
    {
        $this->adresses->removeElement($adresses);
    }

    /**
     * Get adresses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAdresses()
    {
        return $this->adresses;
    }
}
```

**PanierAdresse Controller**

```
<?php

namespace Saresso\SaressoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\UtilisateurAdresse;
use Saresso\SaressoBundle\From\UtilisateurAdresseType;

class PanierController extends Controller {

 public function adresseAction()
    {
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $entity= new UtilisateurAdresse();  //On instantie la table utilisateurAdresse
        $form= $this->createForm(new UtilisateurAdresseType(), $entity); //On instantie le formulaire généré par le fichier UtilisateurAdresseType


        //On verifie si le formulaire est posté par une method POST
        if($this->get('request')->getMethod()=='POST')
        {
            $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest()); //On recupere le contenu du formulaire posté

            //S'il est valide on flush le contenu
            if($form->isValid()){
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //On instantie l'entity manager
                //$entity->setUtilisateur($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()); //On definie l'utilisateur pour le quel on ajoute l'adresse
                $entity->setUtilisateur($user);
                $em->persist($entity); //On prepare la requete à l'aide de doctrine grace à l'entity manager
                $em->flus(); //On insert maintent les données

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('adresse'));
            }
        }
        return $this->render('SaressoSaressoBundle:Default:panierAdress.html.twig', array('utilisateur'=>$user,
                                                                                           'entity'=>$entity,
                                                                                           'form'=>$form->createView()));
    }

}
```

Comment: you get a $user but that is not what you should have for your setter. Try do to ` $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();` then get the good user with `$em->getRepository(theRepo)->find($user->getId())`, Tell me if it works and i'll do a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this code in the class `UtilisateurAdresse` needs to be changed:

```
/**
 * Set utilisateur
 *
 * @param \Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs $utilisateur
 * @return UtilisateurAdresse
 */
public function setUtilisateur(\Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs $utilisateur)
{
    $this->utilisateur = $utilisateur;

    return $this;
}
```

Added the `\Entity` path. Can you try that - i think that is the problem but not certain?